# How to create Type RECORD of INTEGER in my terraform file for BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, schema, terraform, record, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to make the terraform schema for my BigQuery table and I need a column of type RECORD which will be populated by INTEGER.
The field in question would have the format of brackets with integers inside could be one or mutiple seperated by comma : [1]

I tried writing like this:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "categories" {
  project = "abcd-data-ods-${terraform.workspace}"
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.bq_dataset_op.dataset_id
  table_id = "categories"

schema = <<EOF
    [
        {"type":"STRING","name":"a","mode":"NULLABLE"},
        {"type":"RECORD[INTEGER]","name":"b","mode":"NULLABLE"}
    ]
EOF

}
```

and like this:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "categories" {
  project = "abcd-data-ods-${terraform.workspace}"
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.bq_dataset_op.dataset_id
  table_id = "categories"

schema = <<EOF
    [
        {"type":"STRING","name":"a","mode":"NULLABLE"},
        {"type":"RECORD","name":"b","mode":"NULLABLE"}
    ]
EOF

}
```

But it didn't work as I keep getting an error in my CI/CD on gitlab
The error for the first attempt:

```
Error: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for type: RECORD[INTEGER] is not a valid value, invalid
```

The error for the second attempt:

```
Error: googleapi: Error 400: Field b is type RECORD but has no schema, invalid
```

I presume that the second implementation is the closet to the solution given the error but it is still missing something
Does anyone has an idea about the right way to declare it

Comment: Can you edit your examples in the question to be a [mcve] that return those errors when ran please?

Comment: I am looking for the proper way to declare a column in a table using terraform as a RECORD of INTEGER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as stated at the second error:

```
Error: googleapi: Error 400: Field b is type RECORD but has no schema, invalid
```

You must provide a schema for RECORD types ([you can read more on the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated)). For instance, a valid example could be:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "categories" {
  project    = "abcd-data-ods-${terraform.workspace}"
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.bq_dataset_op.dataset_id
  table_id   = "categories"

  schema = <<EOF
      [
          {
            "type":"STRING",
            "name":"a",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
          },
          {
            "type":"RECORD",
            "name":"b",
            "mode":"NULLABLE",
            "fields": [{
                "name": "c",
                "type": "INTEGER",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            }]
          }
      ]
  EOF
}
```

Hope can help.